# Unable to change row height in Bootstrap 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, highcharts, bootstrap-4

[image]

Background:

- Bootstrap 4
- 2 rows, 4 columns each
- Each cell contains a visualization using HighCharts

Issue:

- The cells all have a fixed height that cannot be modified

Attempts:

- Inline `height` style for row, and individual cell
- External height for row and individual cell

I have the following `div` within my HTML:

```
<div id="wrap">

    <div class="row">
        <div id="1" class="col-md-3">
            1
        </div>
        <div id="2" class="col-md-3">
            2
        </div>
        <div id="3" class="col-md-3">
            3
        </div>
        <div id="4" class="col-md-3">
            4
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="5" class="col-md-3">
            5
        </div>
        <div id="6" class="col-md-3">
            6
        </div>
        <div id="7" class="col-md-3">
            7
        </div>
        <div id="8" class="col-md-3">
            8
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

My CSS looks like the following:

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#wrap {
    margin:0px;
    padding:15px;
}

.row {
    height: 300px;
}
```

The elements are responsive horizontally and display properly with the proper breakpoints. The styles on the row are not having an impact. The pie chart within the "cell" is always a set height.

I thought it may have been the the chart overflowing, but setting a fixed chart in the .js for the chart, makes the chart smaller but keeps the div the same size (elements below are pushed down).

Comment: Highcharts inherits it's height and width from the div that contains it. I do not have any width or height defined. When I tested a height (manually) it resized the visualization but the underlying div did not shrink. Also, an additional test: If I remove the visualization and just do a background color and try to resize the div it does not resize either.

Comment: Sorry but I'm note sure to understand. If you want an overflow for the chart, you can define a container like that : jsfiddle.net/kwvm0ohd/1

Comment: In the example provided, it behaves very similar to what I'm seeing. No matter the width of the window, the height of the chart is unable to be changed. I want to set the chart height at 300px max while keeping the responsiveness.

Answer (score 1):

You said :

> The cells all have a fixed height that cannot be modified

This is normal, because you fixed the height with those lines :

```
.row {
    height: 300px;
}
```

If you want that your charts scale both width and height, with a maximum height of 300px, you can do like this :

1. Calculate the ratio of your desired chart : (height / width) * 100%. 
   Example : ratio of 75% for a chart of 400x300px
2. Add 2 wrapper divs around the chart div :

> ```
> <div class="wrapper">
>     <div class="wrapper-in">
>         <div class="chart"></div>
>     </div>
> </div>
> ```

with those styles :

```
.row > div {
   max-height: 300px;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative; 
  padding-bottom: 75%; /* your calculated ratio */
}

.wrapper-in {
  position: absolute; 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%; 
  max-height: 300px;
}

.chart {
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%;
}
```

You can see an example here : http://jsfiddle.net/kwvm0ohd/3/

Hope that helps.

Comment: Given my code above, the 300px was a test. If I set `.row {
    height: 100px;
}` it should work? As it stands that has no impact on the actual layout.

Comment: Try to replace `.row { height: 100px; }` with `.row > div { max-height: 100px; }` and fix the-max-height of .wrapper-in to 100px. If it doesn't work, don't hesitate to show your code (with chart), il will be more easy to help you.